# Blank screen with vnc on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: xorg, vnc, vncviewer

I am getting just a black screen with a white cursor in VNC Viewer on Windows 10.  I have tried many incantations of x11vnc command with Gnome on Ubuntu 17.10, currently:

```
sudo x11vnc -many -auth /run/user/130/gdm/Xauthority -ncache 10 -noxdamage -usepw -display :0 -forever
```

The behavior that changed recently, is that before I would get display :0 on 5900 when it was through.  Now it says

```
rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
29/12/2017 18:54:59 Autoprobing selected TCP6 port 5901

The VNC desktop is:      ares:1
PORT=5901
```

Comment: I found this completely alternative method.  Killed all of the x11vnc stuff.  Started vino server instead.  On windows, launched xming,  launched Putty ssh with X11 forwarding and tunneling.   Then,  on Ubuntu started vinagre with VNC protocol and no tunneling.  However, the response is pretty slow.

Comment: Remmina as VNC is a little faster than Vinagre, but I am  still slowed a bit by  X11 and Xming.